# Meaning of ありじゃないかなぁ

Tags: expressions

I was asking if something is possible or not, and received the "ありじゃないかなぁ" answer below.

I had never heard this expression, is my translation correct?

> Q: 独習×ゲーム的なソーシャルウェブサイトは可能ですか？
>
> A: 聞いてみないとわからないけど、ありじゃないかなぁ。

My translation of the answer: We have to ask to be sure, but I guess it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

あり is a slang meaning "be acceptable", "can be dealt with", or "be cool", (or, more literally, "exists within the acceptable domain"). See [my answer to this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4642).

As for the question part, you translated the opposite. Here, you have a negation, but that is used rethorically. Just like the English negative tag question `isn't it?` implies affirmative, so does the negative question here.

The whole sentence means

> I am not sure without asking to someone, but isn't it acceptable?
>   I am not sure without asking to someone, but I suppose it is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

To explicit Chocolate's answer and by the way answer gibbon.

ありじゃないか should be read as "[something]じゃないか" that you would basically translate as  "Doesn't/Isn't it [something] ?".
Even as a negative form, turned as a question with the ？/か/かな, it becomes a *positive wonder*. Like a question tag. Plus, you should not see it as a question directed to you, more like the person speaking to him/herself and just expressing his/her wonder out loud.

The [something] itself, can be positive or negative, it does not matter. It will mean "Doesn't/Isn't it [something] ?"

To Gibbon> でしょう／だろう can be used for similar cases. Ex: you don't find something, it would be 100% normal to say "どこでしょう？" speaking to yourself or someone else.

Comment: Not sure how that answers my non-question, but thumbs up. :)

Comment: That Chocolate cannot say かな and だろう are the same. They are not the same but have a common ground of usage and that is what Chocolate was talking about.

Comment: Yes well, even grammar with common usage has subtle differences, that's what I was objecting to. Surely you agree that  "どこでしょう?" and "どこかなぁ" are not completely the same when said to one self.

Comment: @oldergod-san, I didn't mean 「かな」 and 「だろう」 were the same... I said 「~じゃないかな？」 and 「~だろう？」can be the same, and the だろう? that I was talking about in my post is something that you use when seeking for agreement, not the one that you use to say 'I wonder~~?'. That's quite another usage of だろう. I never imagined anyone would confuse these two usage of だろう, so I didn't mention the latter in my post, and treated only the former usage, which has to do with OP.

Comment: I didn't say you said they were the same either by the way.