# Reason for using じゃないですか in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

> 「えとー、隣に人乗る時ありますけど、なんかこう前が壁じゃないですか。」

The translation in the subtitle was “Because, sometimes people do sit next to me but there’s a sort of wall in front of you.”

I don’t understand where the じゃない fits into the translation of where “because” is in the sentence either.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23379/9831

Comment: i’m sorry, i’m afraid that doesn’t answer my question! i don’t understand what the sentence is saying and the translation isn’t making sense. that’s what i would like some help with 

Comment: 「えとー、隣に人乗る時ありますけど、なんかこう前が壁じゃないですか。」の後に、「だから...」「それで...」「なんで...」みたいなこと言ってます？　または、前に、「どうして～～ですか？」とか「なんで～～かというと...」みたいな文脈あります？

Comment: The function of じゃないですか is already explained in the linked question. If you still have trouble making sense of it in the context, please provide some more sentences surrounding this one. I initially thought this was about a situation in an elevator, but it doesn't explain why the translator used "sit" to translate 乗る. Without enough context, I can't tell if "because" in the subtitle is correct.

Comment: before, the first woman said 「私はバスが好きです」and the other woman said 「あ、なんで？」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the post mentioned in comments says, to understand the sentence better, simply substitute じゃないですか with です. Here じゃないですか, roughly speaking, plays a role of "isn't it?" or "right?" (it would be a negation if there wasn't か in the end of the sentence, which, in fact, is a question marker), so the second part of the sentence is a statement that asks (but rather rhetorically) your interlocutor if they agree with your or understand you.