# How to use the colloquial word 「アリ」？

Tags: slang, word-usage

Recently I saw it used and I don’t quite get it. The only source i found said it was like asking if you would do something or if it’s normal to do something? Please help!

Comment: Other dupe candidates: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5115/5010 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4642/5010