# What is this use of アリだ?

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension, particle-って

[image]

My understand of the sentence is

SWAMが悪い(...)のに he's essentially saying "Despite the fact the SWAM are the ones that failed"

話をすり替えやがって they had the nerve of changing the subject

俺たちに虐待の疑いアリだってガサ入れするって

I took it "They said they'll raid us over the suspect of us committing "虐待の疑い".

Which put together the jailer is saying "The SWAM group is the one that failed, but they change the topic and said they'll house search us over the fact we may have committed abuse".

What is the actual grammar of 疑いアリだって?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4642/understanding-%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%82%84%e3%81%aa it might be this アリ, "okay" or "acceptable"

Comment: @OtheJared No, that's a different アリ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アリだ is gramatically a combination of noun あり (which is verb ある nominalized by masu-stem) and auxiliary verb だ. あり/なし are often employed as if they are suffixes (i.e. without particle right before) in order to express presence/absence, like 在庫あり/なし, 可能性あり/なし, 才能あり/なし. However, when it is followed by だ, there is little difference between ありだ and ある.

Comment: I think あり＋だ has a different meaning than あり. I think it's more saying that there could be something, or that something is okay

Comment: Gramatically such an interpretation is possible, but not likely because of the context and presence of 「俺たちに」, even though written in Katakana.